# Unable to load class using DexClassLoader, URLClassLoader or PathClassLoader

Tags: android, urlclassloader, dexclassloader

I'm trying to load a class file from a server and instatiante it using
different class loaders, but without success.

I tried `DexClassLoader`, `URLClassLoader` and `PathClassLoader`. Whatever I do, the only thing I get is a `ClassNotFoundException` from `loadClass` method.

First thing I do is to download:

- jar file that contains the class file and the sex file
- jar file that contains the class file but no sex file
- the naked class file

And store it to the apps private storage folder. Then I try to load the class with one of the `ClassLoader` implementations mentioned above causing in:

> Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "FormTestView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/data/[PACKAGE_NAME]/app_test_folder/test.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

Any idea?

Comment: I am getting the same error with `unable to load class com.android.build.gradle.internal.NdkHandler`.  Did you ever resolve your issue?

Comment: Are you using the ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() static method?
Try using the istance method getClassLoader from a Context instance

Answer (score 0):

Did you convert your .jar file using dx tool in android-sdks/build-tools?

If you did not try that, use this command:

```
./dx --dex --output yourJarDexConverted.jar yourJar.jar
```

The resulting yourJarDexConverted.jar file contains classes.dex which is an encrypted file including all the java classes needed by the application distributed as jar.